# Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory Error while upgrading to JSS Update 2

Tags: jss

Getting error while running jss start at my local, attached screen shot for same." Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "~\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react"
Trace:

```
  [1]:  npm run start --                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               sitecore-jss-basicapp@7.0.0 start D:\Sitecore\JSS\V2\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react 
                                                                jss clean && node -r babel-register ./build/start.js --env.content=disconnected                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Cleaning path ./dist...   
                                                                                                                                              D:\Sitecore\JSS\V2\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:328                               throw e;                                                                                                                                                                ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "D:\\Sitecore\\JSS\\V2\\jss-master\\jss-master\\samples\\basic-sample-react"                                        at D:\Sitecore\JSS\V2\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:293:19         
        at Array.map ()                                                                                                                                              at OptionManager.resolvePresets (D:\Sitecore\JSS\V2\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)                                                                                                                                                          at OptionManager.mergePresets (D:\Sitecore\JSS\V2\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)                                                                                                                                                            at OptionManager.mergeOptions (D:\Sitecore\JSS\V2\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:249:14)                                                                                                                                                            at OptionManager.init (D:\Sitecore\JSS\V2\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)                                                                                                                                                                    at compile (D:\Sitecore\JSS\V2\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:103:45)                                         at loader (D:\Sitecore\JSS\V2\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:14)                                          at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\Sitecore\JSS\V2\jss-master\jss-master\samples\basic-sample-react\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)                                                                                                                                                                  at Module.load (module.js:556:32)                                                                                                                                   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                                                npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                                                                                        npm ERR! sitecore-jss-basicapp@7.0.0 start: `jss clean && node -r babel-register ./build/start.js --env.content=disconnected`                                           npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                                                                                  npm ERR!                                                                                                                                                                npm ERR! Failed at the sitecore-jss-basicapp@7.0.0 start script.                                                                                                        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                                                                                    npm ERR!
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to repro the issue on a clean pull of the basic-sample-react sample. I tried installing dependencies via both `yarn` and `npm install`. Based on the error message, it sounds like there may have been an issue installing the `babel-preset-env` module. Can you zip up your `basic-sample-react` folder (including the `node_modules` folder) and send us a link to download - jss@sitecore.net?

Comment: Also, what version of node.js and npm / yarn are you using?

Comment: Shared the file with jss@sitecore.net

Answer (score 3):

It looks like an `npm install` gone bad as there are several dependencies missing from the `node_modules` folder. Can you share what version of node.js and npm you're using? Other than that, I would suggest deleting the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file and running `npm install` again. Or, just run `npm install` again (that worked for me locally on your project).

Comment: It worked now the application is loading :) thank u

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following commands one by one, these are the dependencies which are not added by default, but are required:

`npm install -g ng-cli`

`npm install -g angular-cli`

`npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli`

`npm install`

`npm start`

Just installed the JSS. if those fails try `npm update -g`